# Rails grape api send hash and use present method together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I have got a problem with Grape::API. I need send to the server a hash of total found sport centers:

```
 { :total => total_found }
```

and use a method present together

```
present sport_centers, :with => API::APISportCenterBasic
```

I haven´t got any idea how to do.

I need a `total_found` here because I send to the other server only limited count of sport centers and I need a total count.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `API::APISportCenterBasic.represent sport_centers, total: total_found`

Now you can use `total` in presenter by adding:

```
expose 'total' do |_obj, options|
  options[:total]
end
```